# Looking to grep or egrep year ranges from 1965-1996

Tags: bash, grep

I have a grep that works for some of the dates but having trouble getting my brain to make it fully functional.

```
grep 19[6-9][5-6]$ filename
```

it catches a few correctly but I'm looking to grab all years between 1965-1996.

Here is the current solution but looking for a one line really, but here's what I've gotten so far:

```
grep 196[5-9]$ filename
grep 197[0-9]$ filename
grep 198[0-9]$ filename
grep 199[0-6]$ filename
```

Looking for better and shorter if possible?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Date ranges & regex aren't really that good a match.  If I interpret the $ in your grep correctly the date is the last field on a line.

Try this:

```
awk '$NF >= 1965 && $NF <= 1996' filename
```

If you must use grep it becomes more convoluted:

```
grep -E '196[5-9]|19[78][0-9]|199[0-6]$' filename
```

Comment: This. The `awk` solution is the right answer. Don't use grep to find ranges of numbers, it's way too prone to error and difficult to read and modify later.

Comment: I have only been shown grep, I'm hoping awk will show up soon as awk seems to be the way to go!

Answer (score 3):

You should note that `egrep` allows the `19` to be factored out, like such:

```
grep -E '19(6[5-9]|[78][0-9]|9[0-6])$' filename
```

which might be considered clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `seq` which I find much more readable:

```
grep -E "$(seq -s "|" 1965 1996)" filename
```

-s, --separator=STRING

Comment: Just be careful about the size of the resulting command (and the size of the resulting RE)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ (for i in {1900..2000}; do echo $i; done) | egrep '(196[5..9]|19[78][0-9]|199[0-6])'
1965
1969
1970
1971
1972
1973
1974
1975
1976
1977
1978
1979
1980
1981
1982
1983
1984
1985
1986
1987
1988
1989
1990
1991
1992
1993
1994
1995
1996
```

Answer (score 0):

Using standard `grep` syntax to extract lines ending with any substring number in the inclusive range  1965 to 1996 (this is also *similar* to the attempt by the user in the question):

```bsh
grep -e '196[5-9]$' \
     -e '197[0-9]$' \
     -e '198[0-9]$' \
     -e '199[0-6]$'
```

This extracts lines that end with any of the numbers that you're interested in.  Note that the expressions generally should be quoted.

To avoid matching e.g. `231974` (which matches `1974`) at the end of the line, you may want to insert `\<` at the start of each number in the pattern:

```bsh
grep -e '\<196[5-9]$' \
     -e '\<197[0-9]$' \
     -e '\<198[0-9]$' \
     -e '\<199[0-6]$'
```

This forces the number to be a word and not a substring of some other longer word.